# Formatting Date in Thread safe Manner throws java.text.ParseException:

Tags: java, multithreading, parsing, date

I am trying to convert the date from one format to Another

Input String - 2012-11-07-121603 (yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss)

Output String - 2012-11-07-12:16:03:000  (yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss:SSS)

```
ThreadSafeSimpleDateFormatUtil simpleDateFormat = new ThreadSafeSimpleDateFormatUtil(GenericConstants.DATE_FORMAT.YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS.toString());
final Date parsedDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(bulkCollectionTime);
simpleDateFormat = new ThreadSafeSimpleDateFormatUtil(GenericConstants.DATE_FORMAT.YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS_SSS.toString());
writeBean.setTimestamp(simpleDateFormat.format(parsedDate));
```

But it's throwing below error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2012-11-07-121603"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)
    at com.belgacom.rosy.rebecca.utils.ThreadSafeSimpleDateFormatUtil.parse(ThreadSafeSimpleDateFormatUtil.java:39)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the input format should be without the "-" between hours, minutes and seconds:

```
2012-11-07-121603 (yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Input String - 2012-11-07-121603 (yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss)
```

wrong pattern it would match with `yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss`.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "2012-11-07-121603" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuu-MM-dd-HHmmss" )
).toString()
```

> 2012-11-07T12:16:03

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later. These classes are inherently [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). These classes supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes that are un-thread-safe.

String input = "2012-11-07-121603" ;
    DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuu-MM-dd-HHmmss" ) ;

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` because your input lacks info about time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> ldt.toString(): 2012-11-07T12:16:03

### Thread-safety

The *java.time* classes are designed to be [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). The classes use [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). You may cache objects such as `DateTimeFormatter` for re-use throughout your code and across threads.

## ISO 8601

When serializing date-time values to text, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats only. Do not invent your own formats such as that shown in your Question. The standard formats are practical and sensible. They are designed to be easy to parse by machine yet easy to read by humans across cultures.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. Example shown above.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).